# Smart thread pool for beginners

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a function called :
`Request(out response,string a)` that returns a boolean
I want to run it in multiple threads so I wrote :

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Calss.Request), "");
```

(I'm not sure that the syntax is right)
but the VS keep telling me that the function must have void as a return

```
'expect a method with void request(object)' signature
```

how can I do?

Comment: When you put this in to multiple threads, what are you going to do with the returned bool from `Request` and the value `response`? Please add more code to show how you currently use the code non-threaded and we may be able to help you out.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? The `Task` class and `Task<T>` class are much easier to use if you can use them.

Comment: What is the type of response? And also you should give the call two arguments. And the method need to return void.

Comment: In fact I don't need the value of 'response' , I can ignore it

Comment: @JohnSaunders Saunders I'm using .Net 4.0

Comment: Looks like `Request` needs to have a `void` return type, modify your method to comply with the requirements. Post the full method signature. The one in your OP is missing the type for `response`.

Comment: Then try sth like: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(()=>Calss.Request(out value, "")));` It is untested, I normally work with .net 4.5 and in 4.0 I use `var Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>{}));`

Comment: I have done like that and it works 
SmartThreadPool smart;
smart.QueueWorkItem(
                        new Amib.Threading.Func<HttpWebResponse, string, bool>(CLASS.Request),
                        response, "");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where it helps to look at the documentation a bit.
For the method [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it takes the delegate [WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You need to pass it a method to run that takes a single object, and an object to use as the parameter for the method.

Your method doesn't have the same signature as the callback. The method has the same signature as the `Action<Object>` delegate.

You will have to write a wrapper method for the method that you want to run that has the signature needed:

```
void WrapperMethod(object state)
{
    string a = state.ToString();
    string response;  // whatever this out parameter is...
    Class.Request(out response,a);
}
```

and then set up your thread:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WrapperMethod, "");
```

The compiler will actually set up the delegate for you. If you're running .Net 4.5, you can use `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run(()=> Request(out response, a));
```

Although mixing Task.Run and out parameters is not advised.

Comment: TPL is available in .net 4.0, too ;)

Comment: Yup, you have to use the 4.0 syntax (`Task.Factory.StartNew()`)